# Strange mouse behavior for MacBook

Tags: macos, mouse, macbook, touchpad

In the last three days my mouse click button started acting up. At first sometimes I would click and it would think I clicked twice. Then I would click places and it would not recognize it. And now if I click and it thinks I'm holding down the click button. it does all these three functions interchangeably.

I thought it was just the button on the trackpad itself, but it was doing the same thing when I plugged in a mouse to the USB port. 
My mouse settings appear to be normal. The keyboard commands work fine, so I can still execute functions.

I have a black macbook, version 10.4.11, and it is three years old.
Any thoughts as to what it might be or how to fix this problem?

Comment: The fact that it continues to happen when you plug in an external mouse does not rule out the possibility of intermittent contact in the trackpad button. Does it continue to happen if you boot off your OS installation DVD?

Answer (score 1):

I concur with NSD...  An external mouse has no bearing on your internal trackpad.  If you wish to test the Internal trackpad, you really need to boot from a different source..  The Installer DVD would do nicely.  See if you can duplicate your issue from the installer disc.

If it fails there, then you know it's hardware related.  If you can't duplicate it from the Installer disc, then try a safe boot (hold down left shift key, while rebooting).  If it doesn't occur during a safe boot, then chances are it's a driver issue.

Reboot after the safe boot, and see if it still happens.  Safe booting will cause the OS to rebuild the driver cache, which might resolve the issue, if the driver cache had been damaged....

If it's not resolved, then take a look at your system.  Do you have Logitech drivers, Microsoft drivers, or USB Overdrive installed for your mouse?  Uninstall any mouse related drivers, and see if that affects anything....